# Quero colocar um alert após enviar o formulário pro banco de dados, com uma resposta algo do tipo "Sua mensagem foi enviada."

Tags: php, javascript, html5

**Eu queria que quando o formulário fosse enviado para o Banco aparecesse um alert com algo do tipo "Deu certo inserir" se não desse erro "Erro ao enviar sua mensagem".**

```
<?php 

    if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file'])){
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $connection = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bd', $username );

        $query = "INSERT INTO denuncia (descricao, imagem, id_usuario, oque_descricao,id_bloco, id_denuncia_oque) 
              VALUES (:descricao, :imagem, :id_usuario, :oque_descricao, :id_bloco, :id_denuncia_oque)";

        $statement = $connection->prepare($query);





        $path = "img_denuncia/";
        $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path))



        $valores = array();
        $valores[':descricao'] = $_POST['descricao_denuncia'];
        $valores[':imagem'] = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
        $valores[':id_usuario'] = 2;
        $valores[':oque_descricao'] = $_POST['oque_descricao'];
        $valores[':id_bloco'] = $_POST['bloco_denuncia'];
        $valores[':id_denuncia_oque'] = $_POST['id_denuncia_oque'];



        $result = $statement->execute($valores);


    }
    ?>
```

**Aqui é o Form**

```
<form id="caixa" class="center-block row col-xl-6" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formulario"  method="POST" action="">
            <br>
              <div class="row p-0 no-margin col-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-12" >
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="sel1">Bloco:</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="bloco_denuncia" id="bloco">
                    <option value="1">Bloco - Computação</option>
                    <option value="2">Bloco - Mecânica</option>
                    <option value="3">Bloco - Química</option>
                    <option value="4">Bloco - Administrativo</option>
                    <option value="5">Biblioteca </option>
                    <option value="6">Ginásio </option>
                    <option value="7">Auditório</option>
                    <option value="0">Outros</option>
                  </select>
                  </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="sel1">O que:</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="id_denuncia_oque" id="sel1">
                    <option value="1">Sala</option>
                    <option value="2">Banheiro(térreo)</option>
                    <option value="3">Banheiro(Superior)</option>
                    <option value="4">Labóratorio</option>
                    <option value="5">Coordenação</option>
                    <option value="6">Gabinete</option>
                    <option value="7">Telecom</option>
                    <option value="8">Outros</option>

                  </select>
                  </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="usr">Qual:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" name="oque_descricao" placeholder="ex: ar-condicionado ">
                    </div>

              </div>
               <textarea  id="form-control"class="noresize  col-12 col-sm-12 mb-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-12 " name="descricao_denuncia" placeholder="Responda a denúncia aqui! " id="denuncia" rows="13">
               </textarea>

               <br>
               <div class="row p-0 no-margin col-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-12">  
                    <div class="botao p-0 no-margin col-6 col-sm-6 mb-3 col-md-6 col-lg-2 col-xl-10">
                   <label class="file-upload btn btn-primary">
                        Escolha o arquivo... <input  type="file" name="uploaded_file"/ accept="image/*">
                    </label>  
                   <small class="form-text text-muted">As suas mensagens não serão totalmente anônimas.</small>
                    </div>
                  <div class="botao p-0 no-margin col-6 col-sm-6 mb-3 col-md-6 col-lg-10 col-xl-2 text-right ">
                       <input id="b_enviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enviar" name="enviar"/>
                  </div>insira o código aqui
              </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: mensagem do que e aonde?

Comment: Tipo, quando eu aperta em um botão enviar que tem de baixo da minha caixa de texto quero que avise em algum lugar da tela que, a mensagem foi entregue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ou voce faz assim como o @Reignomo falou, ou você faz um retorno pra uma pagina 
passando por parametro via get um numero tipo

```
if(deucertonophp){
  header('Location: http://www.home.php?msg=1');
}else{
  header('Location: http://www.home.php?msg=2');
}
```

e ai na home você deixa um código php assim

```
if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
   if($_GET['msg'] == 1){
     echo "Deu certo! parabens";
   }
   elseif($_GET['msg'] == 2){
     echo "Deu errado! tente de novo";
   }
}
```

alem desses echo, você pode atribuir o valor de $_GET a uma variavel php, e trabalhar com ela em um modal por exemplo.

Comment: Mas eu coloco o que nesse "DEUCERTOPHP" ? E nesses "($_GET['msg'] == 2) , ($_GET['msg'] == 1)" ?

Comment: esse "deucertoPHP" é uma codição se foi inserido ou não, acho que colocando if($statement->execute($valores)){ funciona!

Comment: Ta dando erro (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF), expecting ',' or ';' in) eu já tirei esse else e deixei so o if e o inverso, mas ainda continua dando erro de syntan. não sai dessa linha. Por favor me ajude '-'

Comment: no caso ficaria assim ?********** if($statement->execute($valores)){
          header('Location: http://localhost/projeto/aluno.php?msg=1');
        }else{
          header('Location: http://localhost/projeto/aluno.php?msg=2');
        }


        if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
           if($_GET['msg'] == 1)
             echo "Deu certo! parabens"
           
           elseif ($_GET['msg'] == 2)
             echo "Deu errado! tente de novo"
           
        }


}

Comment: eu editei, estara dando erro pois esqueci os ; no echo

Comment: Agora deu certo, está indo tudo bem, so não está aparecendo as mensagem "Deu certo! Parabéns" "Deu errado! tente de novo"

Comment: Se você colocou o código 2 que eu postei na home, e apos esse processo ao ir pra home ela aparece coma url http://www.home.php?msg=1 . não tem pq dar erro, talvez você esteja comendo bola em alguma coisa

Comment: O que seria home ? Porque eu coloqui esses dois código um de baixo do outro dentro do php,  if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
   if($_GET['msg'] == 1){
     echo "Deu certo! parabens";
   }
   elseif($_GET['msg'] == 2){
     echo "Deu errado! tente de novo";
   }
}

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso com AJAX da seguinte maneira;

```
if( $result = $statement->execute($valores))
{
 echo 1; // dados enviados com sucesso
}
else
{
// na verdade o else não é necessário mas se preferir pode colocar
 echo 0; // erro ao tentar enviar dados 
}
```

a pagina php que você está o formulário faça um ajax para exibir o alerta, algo como;

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({ 
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url:"PAGINA PHP COM QUE ENVIA OS DADOS",
            success: function(retorno) {
                   if(retorno==1)
                  {
                    alert("Formulário enviado com seucesso");
                  }
                   else
                  {
                    alert("erro ao enviar formulário");
                  }
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
```